# awk - how to ignore wildcard matches?

Tags: awk

I want to process a csv file based on 3rd column value and save the matching lines to a separate file.

`#!/bin/bash
awk -F, '$3 ~ /0/ {print}' ./inputfile.csv > ./out/output.csv`

What I want is only 0 values in 3rd column, but using the above command, the output file contains 3rd column values 0 , 10 , 20 , 100 , etc.. (any value with 0 in it).

How can I tell awk to ignore the wildcard matches and only use absolute 0 value in 3rd column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this:

```
awk -F, '$3 == "0"' ./inputfile.csv > ./out/output.csv
```

`~` is pattern matching, which you don't want here. `==` matches the literal string "0" and nothing else. I also removed the `print` statement since it's implied if you don't give a code block.

You might also consider using a real CSV parsing library, as the syntax can be more complicated than just commas (for example, handling quoting and escaping).

Comment: Note that `$3 == "0"` will only match for `0`, use `$3 == 0` to also match on `00` or `0.0` or `0e2`, or (depending on the awk implementation) `0x0`. Use `!$3` for the same as `$3 == 0` and the empty string. In anycase, none will match on `"0"` (0 surrounded by quotes).

Comment: If you need a strong equity you can use `$3~/^0$/`